# PHP-JavaScript URL decode-encode

Tags: urlencode, urldecode

I need to encode an url in javascript and decode it in php.. how can I do this? I tried using encodeURI and encodeURIComponent functions with urldecode in php but it doesnt work...

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please post some code, what you expect it to output, and what it actually outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding URLs in Javascript should work fine with encodeURI().  See here:

[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

In PHP, if the URL you're reading is being passed through a GET parameter, there's no need to decode it. It's already been done. Otherwise, urldecode() is your answer.

You're gonna need to post more info if you need more help.

Comment: I understood my problem. I am using codeigniter and it ignores comma char in uri. Do you know how I can solve this problem?